# React AG-Grid columns flashing until is fully load

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-column

I am using Ag-grid with callback for onGridReady to add some additional columns. Every time when the grid is loading there are some seconds until columns fully fit the screen. Can I somehow catch the event when the columns are completely ready? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you wait until GridReady to add more columns? Why can't you generate all the column definitions in the beginning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.